# Calling pack() on JDialog doens't shrink it horizontally

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have JDialog with other components set inside it in borderlayout. ComponentListeners are added into the JTextAreas such that the JDialog grows in size when they text area grows.

I increase or decrease the font size of the components with the two buttons increase font size and decrease font size.

Whenever i change the font size, i am calling out on pack() to pack the components. On font increase everything works fine . All components are laid out well. However when i decrease the font size to the lowest possible value, the width remains the same and only the height changes. I want both the height and width to change. I  doubt that im doing something wrong with the layouts.

I am setting only the minimumSize of the Jdialog.

```
public class MyDialog implements ActionListener{

    private  int itsFontSize = 15;

    JPanel itsTitlePanel;

    JPanel itsMainPanel;

    JPanel itsInnerPanel;

    JPanel itsButtonPanel;

    JDialog myDialog;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame dialogOwner = new JFrame();
        MyDialog myyDialogInstance = new MyDialog();
        myyDialogInstance.createDialog(dialogOwner);

        dialogOwner.setVisible(true);


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public JDialog createDialog(JFrame dialogOwner)
    {
        myDialog = new JDialog();

        myDialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        myDialog.setModal(true);
        myDialog.setUndecorated(true);
        myDialog.setResizable(false);
        myDialog.setOpacity(0.9F);

        myDialog.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 200));

        myDialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // title panel
        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("My Title");
        titleLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, itsFontSize));

        itsTitlePanel = new JPanel();
        itsTitlePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        itsTitlePanel.setOpaque(true);
        itsTitlePanel.add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        myDialog.add(itsTitlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);



        createMainPanel();
        myDialog.add(itsMainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        createButtonPanel();
        myDialog.add(itsButtonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        myDialog.setVisible(true);
        dialogOwner.add(myDialog);



        return myDialog; 
    }

    public void createMainPanel()
    {
        createInnerPanel();

        itsMainPanel = new JPanel();
        itsMainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight =1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        itsMainPanel.add(itsInnerPanel,c);

        for(int i =1 ; i<3;i++)
        {
            JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
            textArea.setOpaque(true);
            textArea.setBackground(Color.gray);
            textArea.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {

                @Override
                public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                    myDialog.revalidate();
                    myDialog.pack();
                }

                @Override
                public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

            textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            textArea.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, itsFontSize));
            textArea.setLineWrap(true);
            textArea.setText("Blue mooonnnnn dayyyy apart frommm chalengeee boww bowww coww owww dogggyyy");

            c.gridy = i;
            c.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10);
            itsMainPanel.add(textArea, c);
        }

    }

    public void createInnerPanel()
    {

        itsInnerPanel = new JPanel();
        itsInnerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight =1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10);

        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            JButton button = new JButton();
            button.setText("Inner " + (i+1));
            button.setOpaque(true);
            button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, itsFontSize));

            c.gridx = i;

            itsInnerPanel.add(button, c);
        }
    }

    public void createButtonPanel()
    {
        itsButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        itsButtonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 5, 5));

        for(int i = 0 ; i <3 ; i ++)
        {
            JButton button = new JButton();
            if(i==0)
            {
                button.setText("Increase font size");
            }
            else if(i==1)
            {
                button.setText("Decrease font size");
            }
            else
            {
                button.setText("Close Dialog");
            }
            button.setOpaque(true);
            button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, itsFontSize));
            button.addActionListener(this);
            button.setActionCommand("Button " + (i+1));
            itsButtonPanel.add(button);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(actionEvent.getActionCommand().equals("Button 1"))
        {
            if(itsFontSize <= 48)
            {
                itsFontSize +=2;
                setComponentsWithLatestFontSize();
            }
        }
        else if(actionEvent.getActionCommand().equals("Button 2"))
        {
            if(itsFontSize >= 17)
            {
                itsFontSize -= 2;
                setComponentsWithLatestFontSize();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            myDialog.dispose();;
        }
    }

    public void setComponentsWithLatestFontSize()
    {
        if(itsTitlePanel != null)
        {
            for(Component comp : itsTitlePanel.getComponents())
            {
                Font oldFont = comp.getFont();
                if(oldFont != null)
                {
                    comp.setFont(new Font(oldFont.getName(), oldFont.getStyle(), itsFontSize));
                }
            }
        }

        if(itsMainPanel != null)
        {
            for(Component comp : itsMainPanel.getComponents())
            {
                Font oldFont = comp.getFont();
                if(oldFont != null)
                {
                    comp.setFont(new Font(oldFont.getName(), oldFont.getStyle(), itsFontSize));
                }
            }
        }

        if(itsButtonPanel != null)
        {
            for(Component comp : itsButtonPanel.getComponents())
            {
                Font oldFont = comp.getFont();
                if(oldFont != null)
                {
                    comp.setFont(new Font(oldFont.getName(), oldFont.getStyle(), itsFontSize));
                }
            }
        }

        if(itsInnerPanel != null)
        {
            for(Component comp : itsInnerPanel.getComponents())
            {
                Font oldFont = comp.getFont();
                if(oldFont != null)
                {
                    comp.setFont(new Font(oldFont.getName(), oldFont.getStyle(), itsFontSize));
                }
            }
        }
        myDialog.revalidate();

    }
```

Comment: From the documentation [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--) "Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents". Are you using preferred size?

Comment: no i am not using preferred size for any of the components . I am using only the minimum size of the JDialog.

Comment: That is why it's not working for you, read the documentation and try again

Comment: Okay. Thanks! Will give it a try

Comment: A little debugging shows the `componentResized(ComponentEvent)` is only called on increasing the font size, but not decreasing it. This happens with both the text areas or buttons.

Comment: Setting the preferred size doesn't solve it. The dialog doesn't get resized dynamically on font increase action, when i have the preferred size set.

Comment: This is what i observed : When i increase the font size with  only the minimum size set for the JDialog, the layout managers caculate the preferred size of all components and laids them out as i want it. However, on decreasing the font size, the layout managerdoes recallculate the preferred size of the components, but for the text area alone the width of the preferred size doesn't change , it recalculates only the height. I want the layout manager to even recalculate the width of the preferred size for text arreas. can that be done?

Comment: *"This is what i observed :"* Tip: Add @TzachSolomon (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you for the tip.